# How do I store the content generated?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I have a code as shown below.This code throws our values says, 0.5 seconds on the output screen since I have run a **foreach** loop. Now, I want to work around with my variables **$var1**,**$var2**,**$var3** (which is are got my a imposing a few functions on $value).

```
foreach ($predefinedarray as $key => $value) {
if ($predefined_var == NULL) {
 print "<b>$value</b> could not be processed.<p>";
 } else {
print "$var1,$var2,$var3>";
 }
}
```

Now, I want to get all **$var1** after the whole foreach is done with the constraint that **$var2 = "foo"**; How do I do this? Do i need to use SQL Databases for this or is there a simpler way of using javascript, jquery etc?

**PS:** Also, I want to make a download option that lets me download this data. So, I'm assuming once I figure out how the above data is tored, I can probably work around this too.

Thanks!
John

Comment: Your question is a little unclear could you perhaps show us where you get the values of `$var1, $var2, $var3` ? Are they inside you `$rawlist` array ?

Comment: Hi, yes. Like i mentioned, they are got by a few functions on value. But no, they process the `$value` of `$rawlist` to give `$var1,$var2,$var3`

Comment: Could you please add the function in your question, that you're using to get the Values of `$var1 - 3` :) ? Unless it's too large of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't really got what you were trying to say but as i understood
1)you iterate array and get the values suppose $value
2)you do something with $value and get 3 values $var1,$var2,$var3
3) you want the all $var1 when $var2="foo"

if this is what the question is then i suggest you create another array and fill the with $var1 data when $var2="foo" like

```
$the_var1_array=array();
foreach ($rawlist as $key => $value) {
    if ($id == NULL) 
     {
         print "<b>$value</b> could not be processed.<p>";
     } 
     else 
     {
        print "$var1,$var2,$var3>";
        if($var2=="foo")
        {
           $the_var1_array[]=$var1;
        }
     }
    }
```

Now that you have the array iterate through it and get all the $var1

Hope I understand the question right

Comment: I thought of that. But what if my "foo" is some variable that depends on my input array from the user?

Comment: store input from user in the variable eg $input_var then instead of 
if($var2=="foo") use if($var2=$input+var)...

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of that. But what if my "foo" is some variable that depends on my input array from the user?

Isn't that exactly what $varx are also? Function results depending on the input ($rawlist)?